# How to discard an QEvent instead of just ignoring it

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, drag, qevent

I have two widgets `ParentWidget` and `ChildWidget` both being derived from `QWidget` and both overriding `void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)`.

Now `ChildWidget` is contained in the `ParentWidget`. Now assume that a certain `QDragEvent*` called `event` might be valid for `ParentWidget`, but not for `ChildWidget` and assume that `dragEnterEvent` for `ChildWidget` is called.

Now I can just call `event->ignore()` in order to ignore the event for `ChildWidget`, but then `dragEnterEvent` for `ParentWidget` is called.

And this is my problem. I don't want, that `dragEnterEvent` for `ParentWidget` is getting called, if the event was already discarded in `ChildWidget`.

Simply speaking I just don't want the event just to be ignored, but moreover the event needs to be completely discarded inside the `dragEnterEvent` of `ChildWidget`.

How can achieve such a behavior under the assumption that `ParentWidget` and `ChildWidget` are loosely coupled components?

**Minimal Example**

The following example shows what I'm trying to achieve and also is a workable approach in some sense. In case of more complicated scenarios it would result in overly complicated code.

The `ChildWidget` accepts drop of filenames ending with `txt`, whereas the `ParentWidget` accepts all drops, except the ones already ignored by `ChildWidget`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "ParentWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto widget=new ParentWidget;
    widget->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

**ParentWidget.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

#include "ChildWidget.h"

class ParentWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ParentWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        setAcceptDrops(true);
        layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("ParentLabel"));
        layout()->addWidget(new ChildWidget);
    }

    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override {
        qDebug() << "Parent";
        // Check if event was already ignored in ChildWidget? 
        if (auto childWidget = qobject_cast<ChildWidget*>(childAt(event->pos()))) {
            event->ignore();
        }
        else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
};
```

**ChildWidget.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class ChildWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ChildWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        setAcceptDrops(true);
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("ChildLabel"));
    }

    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override {
        qDebug() << "Child";
        if (auto mimeData=event->mimeData()) {
            auto url = QUrl(mimeData->text());
            if (!url.isValid()) { event->ignore(); return; }
            if (!url.isLocalFile()) { event->ignore(); return; }
            auto filename = url.fileName();
            if (!filename.endsWith(".txt")) { event->ignore(); return; }
            // ChildWidget can only process txt files.
            qDebug() << url.fileName();         
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
        else {
            event->ignore();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation ? You can reimplement ```dragEnterEvent``` for ```ChildWidget``` because it's a virtual

Comment: @ThibautB., I implemented `dragEnterEvent` for both widgets, `ChildWidget` and `ParentWidget`. It's just that `dragEnterEvent` for `ParentWidget` should behave differently, if the event was ignored in `dragEnterEvent` of `ChildWidget`.

Comment: @ThibautB. Can `QDragEnterEvent` transport this boolean?

Comment: If you use a class variable yes, I think

Comment: @ThibautB., I found a workaround for me problem. In case there is a child widget at the events position I knew that the event was already previously ignored in the child widget. Hence I can also ignore it in the parent widget. 

Following code goes in `dragEnterEvent` of the `ParentWidget`.
`if (auto childWidget = childAt(event->pos())) {
  event->ignore();
}`

Comment: it's weird, your method signature are the same ? But if you have a solution... ;) however ```dragEnterEvent``` of ```ChildWidget``` should be called without call ```dragEnterEvent``` of ```ParentWidget```

Comment: I really need to strip my code in order to create a minimal example. It's really to confusing. I guess. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143845/discussion-between-thibaut-b-and-aleph0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the event to be discarded, you need to **accept** it:

```
void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override {
    qDebug() << "Child";
    if (auto mimeData=event->mimeData()) {
        [...]         
        event->acceptProposedAction();
    }
    else {
        event->setAction(Qt::IgnoreAction);
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

This is how Qt dispatch events to widgets: the event is propagated from child to parent until a widget accepts it.

From Qt code:

```
while (w) {
    if (w->isEnabled() && w->acceptDrops()) {
        res = d->notify_helper(w, dragEvent); // calls dragEnterEvent() on w
        if (res && dragEvent->isAccepted()) {
            QDragManager::self()->setCurrentTarget(w);
             break; // The event was accepted, we break, the event will not propagate to the parent 
        }
    }
    if (w->isWindow())
        break;
    dragEvent->p = w->mapToParent(dragEvent->p.toPoint());
    w = w->parentWidget();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to this cool solution. I also found a quite similar solution yesterday. I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a decent workaround.

Alternatively, you can change the event type to a non-drag event. Since the event ceases to be a `QDragEnterEvent`, it won't get dispatched to the parent. There are two ways to implement it: one is to change the `t` (type) member of `QEvent`. Another is to destruct the event in-place and re-create a plain null event there.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/event-discard-43885834
#include <QtWidgets>

void wipeEvent(QEvent * event) {
   struct Helper : QEvent {
      static void wipe(QEvent * e) {
         static_cast<Helper*>(e)->t = QEvent::None;
      }
   };
   Helper::wipe(event);
}

void wipeEvent2(QEvent *event) {
   event->~QEvent(); // OK since the destructor is virtual.
   new (event) QEvent(QEvent::None);
}

class ChildWidget : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QHBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QLabel m_label{"ChildLabel"};
public:
   ChildWidget() {
      setAcceptDrops(true);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_label);
   }
   void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override {
      qDebug() << "Child";
      while (auto mimeData=event->mimeData()) {
         auto url = QUrl(mimeData->text());
         if (!url.isValid()) break;
         if (!url.isLocalFile()) break;
         auto filename = url.fileName();
         if (!filename.endsWith(".txt")) break;
         // ChildWidget can only process txt files.
         qDebug() << url.fileName();
         return event->acceptProposedAction();
      }
      wipeEvent(event);
   }
};

class ParentWidget : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QHBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QLabel m_label{"ParentLabel"};
   ChildWidget m_child;
public:
   ParentWidget() {
      setAcceptDrops(true);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_label);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_child);
   }
   void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override {
      qDebug() << "Parent";
      event->acceptProposedAction();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char** args) {
   QApplication app{argc, args};
   ParentWidget widget;
   widget.show();
   app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long chat yesterday I found the following better solution to my problem. The solution is similar to the one of Benjamin T. Many thanks again to ThibautB. for the fruitful discussion.

Here goes my working code.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "ParentWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto widget=new ParentWidget;
    widget->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

**ChildWidget.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
//#include "MyDragEnterEvent.h"

class ChildWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ChildWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        setAcceptDrops(true);
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("ChildLabel"));
    }

    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) {
        qDebug() << "Child";
        if (auto mimeData=event->mimeData()) {
            auto url = QUrl(mimeData->text());
            if (!url.isValid()) { event->setDropAction(Qt::DropAction::IgnoreAction); event->ignore(); return; }
            if (!url.isLocalFile()) { event->setDropAction(Qt::DropAction::IgnoreAction); event->ignore(); return; }
            auto filename = url.fileName();
            if (!filename.endsWith(".txt")) { event->setDropAction(Qt::DropAction::IgnoreAction); event->ignore(); return; }
            // ChildWidget can only process txt files.
            qDebug() << url.fileName();     
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "Ignored in Child";
            event->setDropAction(Qt::DropAction::IgnoreAction);
            event->ignore();
        }
    }
};
```

**ParentWidget.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

#include "ChildWidget.h"

class ParentWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ParentWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        setAcceptDrops(true);
        layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("ParentLabel"));
        layout()->addWidget(new ChildWidget);
    }

    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override {
        if (event->dropAction() == Qt::IgnoreAction) {
            qDebug() << "Ignored in Parent";
            event->ignore();
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "Accepted in Parent";
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
};
```